# C++ mergesort two passes to display polynomial in order lowest to highest

Tags: c++

What I would like to do is have the first pass go through to check deg and put it into lowest to highest...Then do the second pass and do the coef and put that lowest to highest.

I'm getting segmentation fault...I was wondering if the two if statements is even possible

```
Poly merge(Poly* plist1,Poly* plist2){
  Term **pp;
  Poly merged,list1,list2;
  merged = new_Term(); //function for new term in another file
  list1 = *plist1;
  list2 = *plist2;
  pp= &merged;
  while(list1 != NULL && list2 != NULL){
    if(list2->deg < list1->deg)
      {
        *pp = list1;
        list1 = list1->next;
        (*pp)->next = NULL;
      }
    else
      {
        *pp = list2;
        list2 = list2->next;
        (*pp)->next = NULL;
      }
    if(list2->coef < list1->coef)
      {
        *pp = list1;
        list1 = list1->next;
        (*pp)->next = NULL;
      }
    else
      {
        *pp = list2;
        list2 = list2->next;
        (*pp)->next = NULL;
      }
    pp = &( (*pp)->next );

  }
  if(list1 != NULL)
    *pp = list1;
  if(list2 != NULL)
    *pp = list2;

  *plist1 = NULL;
  *plist2 = NULL;
  return merged;
}
```

Comment: Why not just sort it by coefficient? It seems kinda of redundant.

Comment: You're probably getting segmentation fault because it seems like (to me) that you should be checking the *pp->next/pp value to verify it's not null.

Comment: Removing deprecated homework tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM I think I found my problem...I needed to make it into an if...else if statement and delete one of the

```
else
  {
    *pp = list2;
    list2 = list2->next;
    (*pp)->next = NULL;
  }
```

blocks

Thanks anyways for those fast responders

Update:

Also I needed to change

```
if(list2->deg > list1->deg)
```

To

```
if(list2->coef < list1->coef)
```